# Probability of at least 2 successes in 4 trials

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I'd like to find the probability of *at least* 2 successes in 4 trials (with the probability of succes *p=0.5*), as I found the correct solution for it would be the following:

$\sum_{j=2}^4\begin{pmatrix}4\\j\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^4} = 6\times \frac{1}{2^4}+4\times \frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}$,

but why I couldn't find this probability just writing it:

$\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^4} = 6\times \frac{1}{2^4}$?

Comment: Because the latter expression is the probability of getting *exactly* two successes out of four trials (assuming success probability $\frac 12$, which you never specified).

Comment: @lulu, yes, it's intuitively clear, but what I actually sum up: exact probability of 3 out of 4 successes and 4 out of 4 successes - the all possible success cases, would it be correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct interpretation, and that's what the top calculation does.  The bottom calculation is just one of the relevant cases.

Comment: ok, thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting *at least* $2$ successes is simply the probability of getting *exactly* $2$ successes plus the probability of exactly $3$, plus the probability of exactly $4$:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^4{P(k)}
$$
Now what is the probability of getting exactly $2$ successes? This can happen in many ways, Trials $1$ and $2$ are successful, the others not; $1$ and $3$ successful, etc.. You can pick any $2$ Trials from the four to be successful, so there are $\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}$ ways to have exactly $2$ successful trials.

In each of these combinations, you need two **specific** trials to be a success, and the other two to be a failure. Let's name these trials $\{T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4\}$, such that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the ones that **must** be successful, and $T_3$ and $T_4$ **must** be failures. So the probability of each of these combinations occuring is:
$$
P(T_1) \cdot P(T_2) \cdot P(\lnot T_3) \cdot P(\lnot T_4)
$$
Which in your case is:
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
= &\frac{1}{2}^4
\end{align}
$$
So there are $\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}$ ways to have exactly $2$ successful trials, each of which with a $\frac{1}{2}^4$ probability, so your total probability of exactly $2$ trials successful is:
$$
P(2)=\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}^4
$$
What about $3$ and $4$ successes? If you go back through the same process, you get:
$$
P(3)=\displaystyle\binom{4}{3}\frac{1}{2}^4 \\
P(4)=\displaystyle\binom{4}{4}\frac{1}{2}^4
$$
And we see that in general:
$$
P(n)=\displaystyle\binom{4}{n}\frac{1}{2}^4
$$
So your total probability of *at least* $2$ successes is:
$$
\begin{align}
&\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^4{P(k)} \\
=\space&\boxed{\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^4{\displaystyle\binom{4}{k}\frac{1}{2}^4}}\\
\end{align}
$$
It is important to remember that the result we got for $P(2)$ is the probability of *exactly* $2$ successes, not *at least* $2$, for that you need the sum.